# Backspace behavior on terminal

Tags: terminal, fedora, python, zsh

I opened a `zsh` in a remote computer running Fedora 13 (yeah, it's old). When typing <kbd>backspace</kbd> everything works fine, but nothing happens when I type <kbd>home</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> does the job as expected). But when launching a python 2.7 subshell, my <kbd>backspace</kbd> prints `^?` instead of removing the latest character and <kbd>home</kbd> prints `^[OH`, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> prints `^A`.

That's not the behavior I see when I'm in my usual Linux Mint in local machine, where everything works fine. Does anyone knows how come this happens and what could I do to solve this out? Thank you

Comment: These are two separate problems. The Python interpreter should be using Readline, whereas zsh uses its own line editing library. I don't know much about zsh, so I can't help you there. What version of Python is on the system and what, if anything, is the value of the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable?

Comment: @Brandon Thank you. The system normally uses python2.4, but I installed my own python2.7.5 and I'm opening it by calling the path to 2.7.5. Now `echo $PYTHONSTARTUP` prints an empty line. And my `PATH` begins with the `bin` directory where python2.7.5 is. Is it possible it is trying to access configurations of ancient versions of python? Each user has installed its own python there.

Comment: Is it possible that you disabled Readline support when you built Python? Try rebuilding it, specifying `--enable-readline` as an option to the `configure` script.

Comment: You might be able to do something by editing your `~/.inputrc` file.

Comment: @BrandonInvergo, if I rebuild it, will I lose all installed packages?

Comment: I don't *think* so, but as always, be safe and make a back-up.

Comment: It does not recognize it `configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-readline`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BrandonInvergo pointed out in the comments, these are two different issues. As I don't know python, I only concentrate on the `zsh` specific problem.

The Z shell uses the *Z line editor* (zle) to interact with the user. The key bindings are configured with the `bindkey` builtin (see `man zshzle` for more detailed informations). There are different keymaps, e.g. when you type at the prompt, the `main` keymap is active, if you use `zed` (a simple, but often very convenient file editor), the keymap `zed` is active etc.

You can display the current key bindings with `bindkey -M [keymap]`, the `main` keymap is the default, so in *most* cases you can simply omit the `-M [keymap]` parameter.

Now, let's have a look at your specific problem:

`CTRL+A` (represented by `^A`) jumps to the beginning of the line, so you probably used `bindkey -e` somewhere in your RC files (either in your personal `~/.zshrc`, but it could also be issued in some system wide config like `/etc/zshrc`) to activate the `emacs` key bindings:

```
$ zsh -f
$ bindkey -e
$ bindkey | head -n 3
"^@" set-mark-command
"^A" beginning-of-line
"^B" backward-char
```

To have the same behavior for the `HOME` key, you need to identify the produced string (which depends on your terminal emulator you use). A simple trick is to fire up `cat` and press the desired key. This is the output using `xterm` for the `HOME` and `END` key:

```
$ cat
^[[H^[[F
```

So, long text, short message -- you want to put these lines in your `~/.zshrc` file (but *after* the `bindkey -e` command):

```
bindkey "^[[F" end-of-line
bindkey "^[[H" beginning-of-line
```

And please don't forget to `source ~/.zshrc`... then these two key should work as desired.

Comment: Thank you, I'm kinda new in `zsh`. Indeed, my strings for `home` and `end` are `^[OH` and `^[OF`, then it works. And as I am more used to `vi`, I used `bindkey -v` to activate `viins` key bindings instead.